# how volatile keyword Influences atomicity when defining a long or double variable

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm recently reading the thinking in java,and confused by below:

> However, you do get atomicity (for simple assignments and returns) if you use the volatile keyword when defining a long or double variable (note that volatile was not working properly before Java SE5).

why I can get atomicity if I use the volatile keyword when defining a long or double variable?the JVM is allowed to perform reads and writes of 64-bit quantities (long and double variables) as two separate 32-bit operations and if I define a long or double variable as volatile  two separate 32-bit operations will not be interruptible by the threading mechanism?

The whole paragraph content:

> Atomicity applies to "simple operations" on primitive types except for longs and doubles. Reading and writing primitive variables other than long and double is guaranteed to go to and from memory as indivisible (atomic) operations. However, the JVM is allowed to perform reads and writes of 64-bit quantities (long and double variables) as two separate 32-bit operations,raising the possibility that a context switch could happen in the middle of a 
>   read or write, and then different tasks could see incorrect results (this is sometimes called word tearing, because you might see the value after only part of it has been changed). However, you do get atomicity (for simple assignments and returns) if you use the volatile keyword when defining a long or double variable (note that volatile was not working properly before Java SE5). Different JVMs are free to provide stronger guarantees, but you should not rely on platform-specific features.

Volatile fields are immediately written through to main memory,and reads occur from main memory.So even I define a long or double variable as volatile,the 32-bit operation can happen and change the long or double value in the main memory,at the time the writing long or double value contains two 32-bit operations and the first 32-bit operations can happen before to change the value in the main memory.
thanks.

Comment: What was the question?

Comment: @Kayaman I believe it is something like: Since 64 bit primitive read/write operations are not atomic by default, does making a variable `volatile` change this behaviour?

Comment: Volatile does make 64 bit primitive operations atomic (since 1.5) so that you can't have only half the value written, but more importantly it makes the updates (whether 64 or 32 bit) immediately visible to other threads.

Comment: @Kayaman The later part isn't really true. It only establishes a hb relationship with other reads of the same variable, which is not the same as "immediately visible to other threads". Same goes for "Volatile fields are immediately written through to main memory" - that's *one* possible implementation, but in practice that's actually not what happens on all architectures, although at least that one is a relatively non-leaky abstraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such cases it's best to just look it up in the JLS:

[17.7. Non-atomic Treatment of double and long](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.7):

> For the purposes of the Java programming language memory model, a
>   single write to a non-volatile long or double value is treated as two
>   separate writes: one to each 32-bit half. This can result in a
>   situation where a thread sees the first 32 bits of a 64-bit value from
>   one write, and the second 32 bits from another write.
>
> Writes and reads of volatile long and double values are always atomic.
>
> Writes to and reads of references are always atomic, regardless of
>   whether they are implemented as 32-bit or 64-bit values.

On a side note "Volatile fields are immediately written through to main memory,and reads occur from main memory" isn't really true. That's one possible implementation, but how the JVM actually does implement the guarantees given by volatile is its own decision. Depending on the cache coherency protocol of the underlying hardware there are other, better solutions.

On the other hand it's imaginable that guaranteeing this on some low-level hardware would involve some software locks to avoid torn reads/writes. Inefficient? Yes, but the JVM is perfectly free to do so if it wants.